# Split number into groups of 3 digits

Tags: c#, parsing

I want to make a method that takes a variable of type `int` or `long` and returns an array of `int`s or `long`s, with each array item being a group of 3 digits. For example:

```
int[] i = splitNumber(100000);
// Outputs { 100, 000 }

int[] j = splitNumber(12345);
// Outputs { 12, 345 }

int[] k = splitNumber(12345678);
// Outputs { 12, 345, 678 }
// Et cetera
```

I know how to get the last *n* digits of a number using the modulo operator, but I have no idea how to get the *first* n digits, which is the only way to make this method that I can think of. Help please!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without converting to string:

```
int[] splitNumber(int value)
{ 
    Stack<int> q = new Stack<int>();
    do 
    {
        q.Push(value%1000);
        value /= 1000;
    } while (value>0);
    return q.ToArray();
}
```

This is simple integer arithmetic; first take the modulo to get the right-most decimals, then divide to throw away the decimals you already added. I used the Stack to avoid reversing a list.

Edit: Using log to get the length was suggested in the comments. It could make for slightly **shorter** code, but in my opinion it is not **better** code, because the intent is less clear when reading it. Also, it might be less performant due to the extra Math function calls. Anyways; here it is:

```
int[] splitNumber(int value)
{
    int length = (int) (1 + Math.Log(value, 1000));
    var result = from n in Enumerable.Range(1,length)
                 select ((int)(value / Math.Pow(1000,length-n))) % 1000;
    return result.ToArray();           
}
```

Comment: Also, no list is required. You can calculate the number of threesomes (using log, I think).

Comment: Yeah, you can do that, IMO this is cleaner and has practically no overhead.

Comment: note that this will only work for positive ints, and I suspect that's fine for the OP's use case.

Answer (score 5):

By converting into a string and then into int array

```
int number = 1000000;
string parts = number.ToString("N0", new NumberFormatInfo()
                                            {
                                                NumberGroupSizes = new[] { 3 },
                                                NumberGroupSeparator = "."
                                            });
```

By using Maths,

```
public static int[] splitNumberIntoGroupOfDigits(int number)
{
    var numberOfDigits = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(number) + 1); // compute number of digits

    var intArray = new int[Convert.ToInt32(numberOfDigits / 3)]; // we know the size of array
    var lastIndex = intArray.Length -1; // start filling array from the end

    while (number != 0)
    {
        var lastSet = number % 1000;
        number = number / 1000;

        if (lastSet == 0)
        {
            intArray[lastIndex] = 0;  // set of zeros
            --lastIndex;                    
        }
        else if (number == 0)
        {
            intArray[lastIndex] = lastSet; // this could be your last set
            --lastIndex;                    
        }
        else
        {
            intArray[lastIndex] = lastSet;
            --lastIndex;                    
        }
    }

    return intArray;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try converting it to string first and do the parsing then convert it back to number again

Comment: How does this answer the question of the OP?

Comment: Very interesting, however I would like to (if possible) use a method without conversion.

Comment: @rene it does, since the original question is about splitting a number into groups; however I would like to see if there is a way to do it without converting.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to string

Get length

If length modulus 3 == 0

String substring it into ints every 3

else if 
Find remainder such as one or two left over

Substring remainder off of front of string

Then substring by 3 for the rest

Answer (score 1):

You can first find out how large the number is, then use division to get the first digits, and modulo to keep the rest:

```
int number = 12345678;

int len = 1;
int div = 1;
while (number >= div * 1000) {
  len++;
  div *= 1000;
}

int[] result = new int[len];
for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++) {
  result[i] = number / div;
  number %= div;
  div /= 1000;
}
```

Comment: Nice! I benchmarked the performance of yours against the other methods over 100 million calls, and yours was the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this with the `System.Linq` namespace from .NET 3.5 and above:

```
int[] splitNumber(long value)
{
    LinkedList<int> results = new LinkedList<int>();

    do
    {
        int current = (int) (value % 1000);

        results.AddFirst(current);
        value /= 1000;
    } while (value > 0);

    return results.ToArray();// Extension method
}
```

I use `LinkedList<int>` to avoid having to [`Reverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb358497.aspx) a list before returning.  You could also use [`Stack<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/3278tedw.aspx) for the same purpose, which would only require .NET 2.0:

```
int[] splitNumber(long value)
{
    Stack<int> results = new Stack<int>();

    do
    {
        int current = (int) (value % 1000);

        results.Push(current);
        value /= 1000;
    } while (value > 0);

    return results.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: When I try to compile that, it says that `System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<int> does not contain a definition for 'ToArray'`.

Comment: Bluefire, can you copy and paste your "usings" at the top of the page?

Comment: @Bluefire: I have updated my answer to address your compilation error.